# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Tried to execute unknown prepared query

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-mvc, cassandra-3.0, java-17

com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Tried to execute unknown prepared query . You may have used a PreparedStatement that was created with another Cluster instance

Facing this issue after upgrading application from java 8 to java 17.

Currently we are using datastax driver core 3.3.0 with 3.11.7 cassandra server

```java
private ResultSet execute(BoundStatement boundStatement) {
    queryLogger.debug("Executing : {}", boundStatement.preparedStatement().getQueryString());
    ResultSet resultSet = getSession(boundStatement).execute(boundStatement);
    return resultSet;
}
```

throwing this error while `getSession()` of method called.  `getSession() method implemntation is like this

```java
private Session getSession(BoundStatement boundStatement) {
    return cassandraConfiguration.getSession(boundStatement.preparedStatement().getQueryKeyspace());
}

public Session getSession(String keyspace) {
    if (!sessionCache.containsKey(keyspace)) {
        sessionCache.put(keyspace, createSession(keyspace));
    }
    return sessionCache.get(keyspace);
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't cache/reuse `BoundStatement` only `PreparedStatement` should be re-used.